# Задания по Python

Tags: python, django

Изучаю Python и Django, столкнулся с проблемой практики, сам себе заданий не могу придумать, можете подсказать что делать? Есть опыт с JS, но там показалось все проще, хочется заданий приближенных к реальным проектам на back-end. Может есть менторы? Много не прошу, хоть пару советов, несколько книг пересмотрел, но версии старые для Django например, в офф руководстве не все понимаю.

Comment: лично я всегда ищу курсы по изучаемой теме и прохожу там практические задания. если не могу решить - смотрю теорию для этого задания.

Comment: Я обычно так же, но с Django большая проблема с версиями + проблема с версиями в DB и в итоге курсов как таковых нет нормальных, а с офф руководством у мня не складывается

Comment: Проблема в том, что вопрос "Невозможно дать объективный ответ.
Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе."

Comment: На этот вопрос вполне можно дать однозначный правильны ответ, но дать его может тот кто действительно знает ответ. и справился с такой же проблемой.

Comment: Я понимаю что у тех кто уже давным давно все умеет и знает, не возникает таких вопросов, но я новичок, и у меня есть именно такой вопрос, не другой а именно этот, кто не хочет пусть не отвечает.

Comment: В принципе я могу дать пояснения по моему вопросу, иногда человек не может понять как действовать, и порой стоит посмотреть чужую модель поведения при решении какой либо проблемы, дак вот у программистов  это самая херовая область, есть куча офф документации и курсов по конкретным технологиям но при этом понятнее не становится простое человеческое поведение, как и что сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. зайти на фриланс. найти какое-то задание по душе типа "создать копию того-то сайта" и т.д. и попытаться выполнить. Ну, а если сделаешь, то можешь написать заказчику типа "я сделал, мало опыта, хочу сравнить с тем что сделали вам.". Вот тебе и боевой опыт, отзывы, возможно приглашение поучаствовать в других проектах. Ну и заодно узнаешь сколько бы заработал, если бы все это знал и сделал в срок))
2. Придумать какой-нибудь сайт. Пусть даже блог. Ииии забить на него)))) и просто заниматься обучением. И все что новое узнаешь, реализовывать на этом сайте. Твой сайт будет результатом твоих знаний. Крутой проект может не получится, но по крайней мере это будет комбайн, где реализовано все. И будешь оттуда дергать код на разные проекты.

PS. Сам недавно перешел из фронтенда на бэкенд. Тоже занимаюсь изучением python и django. Я пока на втором варианте)))

Comment: Отличный вариант спасибо, действительно ценный совет

Comment: serezha-kuznetsov@inbox.ru если есть возможность  и время, буду рад знакомству

Answer (score 0):

В этой ситуации могу посоветовать создать самописный сайт для портфолио c использованием Python + Django. На Python же организовать работу и с MySQL, такие проекты существуют в реале. Это будет замечательная возможность проявить себя.

Comment: Я могу создать блог к примеру, то чему учат почти в каждой книге, но интересуют боле масштабные проекты, не стандартные. Где искать практику по ним?  С трудоустройством беда.